# Is a second 'is' in a compound sentence redundant?

Tags: coordination, redundancy

Is it correct is say:

> This file **is** part of X **and** **is** distributed...

or this:

> This file **is** part of X **and** distributed...

What's the rule here?

Comment: There is no rule. Both are common and grammatical. The second *is* lends a little extra emphasis.

Comment: The first *is* is a main verb, and the second *is* is an auxiliary verb. Since they're different grammatically, it's best to repeat the *is*.

Answer (score -1):

When making lists of things, good English style recommends that you write all the elements in exactly the same way.

> The soup is thin, weak, and watery.
>
> The soup is cooked in a tureen, stirred with a spoon, and served in a bowl.

So the question is, are you listing features of the file?  Or mentioning separate but related facts?  Both are fine, but if you want to *imply* multiple features, you would use the pattern:

> the [thing] is [A] and [B]

Otherwise you could repeat "is" to denote the actions are unrelated:

> the [thing] is [A], and then it is [B].

Note again this is simply *style*, not *grammar*.  Both of your examples are fine as written.

Comment: @Peter Shor's [comment about the different uses of *is*](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/81077/is-a-second-is-in-a-compound-sentence-redundant#comment157160_81077) is worth noting.